# find and replace double bracket values

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

I have a requirement to replace the `[[KEY]]` in double brackets in one of the html file with `VALUE`. Key values are available in different files. After replacement, I need to put output in separate file.

Thus, we have two input file and one output file as an argument.

### html file: foo.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>[[title]]</tittle>
</head>
<body>[[body]]</body>
</html>
```

### properties file: foo.properties

```
title=foo title
body= foo body
```

### output file

```
<html>
<head>
<title>foo title</tittle>
</head>
<body>foo body</body>
</html>
```

How can I create my bash script by passing all file names in arguments?

Comment: Is this homework ? What are the exact requirements here - are you supposed to do this shell only (this is normally a job for tools like `sed`/`awk`) ? Finally, what have you tried ?

Comment: bash might not be the best tool for this, though it's surely possible, but perl or python or something similar might be a lot easier

Comment: Running ./script.sh  foo.html foo.properties outputfoo.html will give you me output file. 3 parameters with scrpit. I need bash script as it will fetch properties dynamically in prod environment.

Comment: It looks like you're reinventing [mustache templates](https://mustache.github.io/).  Why not use a standard solution?

Comment: templating like this existed decades before mustache templates was created in 2009.

Comment: If any of the existing answers solves your problem, please consider accepting it via the checkmark. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

With `sed`:

```
sed -f <(sed 's/\(.*\)=\(.*\)/s\/\\[\\[\1\\]\\]\/\2\//' foo.properties) foo.html
```

The inner `sed` invocation builts the search and replace pairs, which then got read by the outer sed via `-f` (script-file).

It creates `sed` commands from the file `foo.properties` as follows:

```
s/\[\[name\]\]/replace string/
```

Those are read and executed against the second file `foo.html`.

Answer (score 1):

Eric Renouf was right, bash is probably not the best tool for this; but that didn't stop me from trying!

The following script uses a bunch of bash-isms to do its work:

1. `mapfile` to read the input file (into the default array MAPFILE), trimming trailing newlines (`-t`)
2. built-in conditional expression `[[` whose only purpose is to find lines from the translation file that look like key=value pairs. The regular expression wants to see at least one character for a key and one for a value.
3. it then builds up a variable `expr` to use as a sed expression.

The bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Usage: $0 [input file] [translation file] [output file]

mapfile -t < "$2"
expr=""
for keyvalue in "${MAPFILE[@]}"
do
  if [[ $keyvalue =~ (.+)=(.+) ]]
  then
     k="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
     v="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
     expr="$expr s/\[\[$k\]\]/$v/g;"
  fi
done
sed "$expr" "$1" > "$3"
```

If I was dedicated, I'd use mapfile again on the input file, loop over the MAPFILE translation array and use `${parameter/pattern/string}` expansion on each input line in order to write a new output file. Maybe later!

Usage: `scriptname foo.html foo.properties outputfoo.html`

When run on the OP's sample input files, outputfoo.html contains:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>foo title</tittle>
</head>
<body> foo body</body>
</html>
```

... leading space for 'foo body' included!

### LATER happened

I got curious enough, and came up with a more bash-y version of the above. Instead of using sed, it uses bash's parameter expansion on each replacement as it loops through the input file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Usage: $0 [input file] [translation file] [output file]

mapfile -t < "$2"
declare -A replacements
for keyvalue in "${MAPFILE[@]}"
do
  if [[ $keyvalue =~ (.+)=(.+) ]]
  then
     k="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
     v="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
     replacements[$k]="$v"
  fi
done

mapfile -t < "$1"
for line in "${MAPFILE[@]}"
do
  for pattern in "${!replacements[@]}"
  do
    line="${line//\[\[$pattern\]\]/${replacements[$pattern]}}"
  done
  printf "%s\n" "$line"
done > "$3"
```